# How to make Java threads to get fair amount of CPU time

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Java. I have searched this site before posting this question. Please forgive me if my question looks stupid.

The have given below the code for which I am looking for answer.

My intention is to have 4 players competing in a 100 meter running race. The Main is threading is running with highest priority, so it can check how far each player progressed. I have coded Yield method in both main and child threads, thinking that both main thread and child will get fair amount of CPU time.

This program produces below three different outputs for each run.

1. It produces ""Gun is Fired" message and after that no message is displayed in the console. Looks like main thread is monopolizing the CPU in this case.
2. Some time one single "Player" objects gets all the CPU time and wins the race and none of the other player objects gets CPU time.
3. Rarely All the players instances get fair amount CPU time and I could see that each player instance produces messages in the console.

The processor in my system is core 2 duo.

Is it possible to always achieve the "3rd output" mentioned above ?.

```
class Player implements Runnable{

    int noOfMetersCrossed = 0;
    Gun gun;
    String name;

    Player(Gun gun,String name) {
        this.gun = gun;
        this.name = name;
        new Thread(this,name).start();
    }

    public void run() {
        try{
            synchronized(gun){
                gun.wait();         
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e){

        }
        System.out.println(name+" started running");
        while(noOfMetersCrossed < 100){
            noOfMetersCrossed++;                
            System.out.println(name + " crossed " + noOfMetersCrossed + " meters");
            Thread.yield();
        }
    }

}

class Gun {
    void fire(){
        synchronized(this){
            System.out.println("Gun is Fired");
            notifyAll();
        }
    }
}


public class Refree {
    public static void main(String arg[]){
        Gun gun = new Gun();
        Player participants[] = new Player[4];

        for(int i=0;i < 4;i++) {
            participants[i] = new Player(gun, "Player "+i);
        }
        Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MAX_PRIORITY);

        gun.fire();
        findWinner(participants);
    }   

    static void findWinner(Player participants[]){      
        outer: while(true){

            Thread.yield();
            for(int i=0;i <4;i++) {
                if (participants[i].noOfMetersCrossed == 100){
                    System.out.println("The winner is " + participants[i].name);
                    break outer;                    
                } 
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I FORGIVE YOU FOR AYNTHING DEAR USER

Comment: Note that depending on the processor/os, the priority you set may be ignored completely.

Comment: On such a small timescale I'm not sure it is possible, without use of synchronization primitives so that threads will wait on the others if they get ahead. I suspect if you made the "race" last a LOT longer you would see more even time allocation among the threads.

Comment: Try making `noOfMetersCrossed` volatile because there's also the issue of visibility here. Without any kind of synchronization around the variable, the referee thread is within its right to always see 0.

Comment: time slice is too long :) 1. notyfyAll is sequential not parallel so one thread starts and in one time slice reach 100m, in another slice main thread detect it and stops JVM so other threads have no chance to make some cpu use. Try to make something more complicated than  i++. BTW: would be better to make  noOfMetersCrossed volatile to  ensure correct visibility from other threads.

Answer (score 3):

The OS tries to divide the CPU equally among the threads.
Instead of the loop waiting for the winner, I would use a CountDownLatch or something like this, because your findWinner is competes for the CPU together with the runners.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone looking at this after 7 years, using System.{out|err}.println() anywhere in the busy loop is a bad idea for this kind of "measurement", simply because console output acquires a monitor lock on the respective console stream. If it didn't, you'd have partial and jambled lines output from multiple threads.

So, the console output in that loop has a side effect that makes those 4 threads wait for each other to output messages on the console. What's worse: monitor locks are not fair.